# Visual Studio Reporting - Return Number Of Records In Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I want to output the number of records that are present in a certain table.

I know where to put the code just don't know the actual terms as SQL Expressions is relatively new to me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of records shown in the table can be returned using the COUNT function. This is a relativity easy function to use/ understand - http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php 
- Good Luck! ^_-

Comment: Hi I feel like I should explain in more detail, the table isn't an SQL table, its a table that is in my report, therefore has the name Tablix1 for example. `=Count(Fields!new_name.Value)` has given me the overall count of the records however it is not counting the ones that are in my report table